# What is the difference between flush, flushinput and flushoutput in python?

Tags: python, flush

I am doing a serial communication in python between a RPi and a camera. I send some data from the RPi using `ser.write()` and read data from the camera in the RPi using `ser.read()`. Then I would like to know what would `ser.flush()`, `ser.flushinput()` and `ser.flushoutput()` do if I add these after the read command.

I assume `ser.flush()` will make the program wait till all data from buffer memory is read. But I don't understand what the other two will do

Can someone tell me, what is the difference between these three when used in serial communication and what will happen when I use each of them separately after the `ser.write()` or `ser.read()`.

Comment: Are you referring to the [pySerial API](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html)? If so, then you should be able to read about their differences. Otherwise, how do you know your code requires a call to flush?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific I'm afraid.  Presumably you're doing some kind of IO, but it's hard to tell -- What object's `flush` or `flushinput` or `flushoutput` method are you calling?

Comment: I am doing a serial communication from a camera. I send some data using ser.write and read it using ser.read. Then I would like to know what would ser.flush , ser.flushinput and ser.flushoutput do if I add these after the read command.

I assume ser.flush will make the program wait till all data from buffer memory is read. But I dont understand what the other two will do